# setting value of thymeleaf form field which have one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to submit form data from thymeleaf where the relationship between the class is one to many. The form has multiple fields with same properties so I'm using array to submit the form. I'm getting field not found exception like this. How do we set the property between the classes that has one to many relationship?

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'education.name[0]' of bean class [pro.budthapa.domain.Resume]: Bean property 'education.name[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

**index.html**

```
<form th:action="@{/resume/new}" th:method="post" th:object="${resume}" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="college">College/University Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{education.name[0]}" placeholder="college /university" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2" for="college">Course:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{education.course[0]}" placeholder="course of study" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="college">College/University Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{education.name[1]}" placeholder="college /university" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2" for="college">Course:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{education.course[1]}" placeholder="course of study" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Entity class**

**Education.class**

```
@Entity
public class Education {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="college_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="course_name")
    private String course;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="resume_id")
    private Resume resume;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public Resume getResume() {
        return resume;
    }

    public void setResume(Resume resume) {
        this.resume = resume;
    }
}
```

**Resume.class**

```
@Entity
public class Resume {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="resume")
    private Set<Education> education;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Education> getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    public void setEducation(Set<Education> education) {
        this.education = education;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

**ResumeController.class**

```
@Controller
public class ResumeController {

    private static final String ADD_RESUME="resume/addResume";

    @Autowired
    private ResumeService resumeService;

    @GetMapping("/resume/new")
    public String addResume(Resume resume, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("resume",resume);
        return ADD_RESUME;
    }

    @PostMapping("/resume/new")
    public String addResume(@Valid Resume resume, BindingResult result, Model model){

        resumeService.save(resume);
        model.addAttribute("resume",resume);
        return ADD_RESUME;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the property navigation slightly wrong, change to this (and similar for the other fields):

```xml
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{education[0].name}" placeholder="college /university" />
```

Then if a remember correctly you must use `List` instead of `Set`:

```
private List<Education> education;

public List<Education> getEducation() {
    return education;
}

public void setEducation(List<Education> education) {
    this.education = education;
}
```

Because a `Set` has no indexes.

Comment: I misplaced the index position wrong. Now, fixed. Turns out we can't use Set because while using empty set it will throw exception like "Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path". Changed it to List and everything is working again.